# Open Office Base Form's record status

Tags: macros

I'm using OpenOffice Base and basic macros to control my forms.

I used to program Microsoft Access-basic and there are certain things I don't know the correspondence in OpenOffice Base macro basic.

How can I retrieve the current record status of a form?

I mean the status that describes if record is in edit-mode, view-mode or new-record mode.

In access basic these statuses are described in a single property that specify whether a record is in:

- EditMode: when a value of a saved record is changed, until hitting save.
- NewRecordMode: when all fields are empty in order user to assign the values of a new record, until hitting save.
- ViewMode: when user is just preview the record, without any of the above actions take place.

Is there any correspondence in OpenOffice Base Macro Basic? Are there any property or something to indicate these statuses?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researching, I found the answer on my own:

```
oForm = ThisComponent.DrawPage.Forms.GetByName("myForm")
oForm.isModified() (boolean for edit mode)
oForm.isNew() (boolean for NewRecord mode)
```

Thanks anyway!